# Is this a property of summations?

Tags: probability, summation

[image]

My main problem comes from understanding the process from line 2 to line 3. Is that a property of  summations that im not aware of? it says in the script that this is a "useful trick".

i can't understand it as a procedure that one performs on the second line to turn it into the third line. I only have a basic understanding of it to be true in terms of the second summation serving to sum P(X=y) (y-1) times.

Comment: You are basically changing the order of your summation. It is not always legal to reorder a double summation. However, the $\mathbb{P}(\cdots)$ here are probabilities and hence non-negative. In this case, you can reorder the summation in any order you like and you get the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

He's just interchanging the order of summation.  In line two, for each $x$, you sum over all $y>x$.  In line 3, for each y you sum over all $x<y$.  But $x<y$ and $y<x$ are equivalent, so you're summing over the same $(x,y)$ pairs in both cases.

**EDIT** I originally reversed "row" and "column" in this explanation.  See the comments.

If you imagine marking the pairs $(x,y)$ in the plane that satisfy these conditions with dots, you get an infinite "triangle" of dots.  In the first case,you sum over the columns, which is inconvenient because they have infinitely many dots, and in the second case, you sum over the rows, which have only finitely many dots, so it's a lot easier.

Comment: Could you put in picture your idea of the ifinite triangle? it was mentioned in my text too but I don't know what it's getting at.

Comment: I'd be glad to, but I don't know how to make pictures.  You can make your own, though.  For $x=0$ any positive $y$ so put some dots on the nonnegative y-axis.  For $x=1$, put some dots at (1,2), (1,3),... .  Then put dots at (2,3), (2,4), etc.  

I'm glad you asked me this, because I see that I had "row" and "column" reversed in my answer.  I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

> The following is valid if all summands are non-negative:
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{x=0}^\infty\sum_{y=x+1}^\infty f(x,y)
> \color{blue}{=\sum_{0\leq x<y<\infty}f(x,y)=}
> \sum_{y=1}^\infty\sum_{x=0}^{y-1}f(x,y)
> \end{align*}

The middle sum might help to see the connection between line $2$ and line $3$.